# Inner join in Insert query?

Tags: c#, sql, insert

I wanna do something like this:

```
insert into TableA 
   (val1,val2) 
values
   ("value",(select top 1 tableB.X from tableB where tableB.Y=@Y))
```

I get this error:

> Subqueries are not allowed in this context. Only scalar expressions are allowed

How to stop that error?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming you're using SQL Server:

```
insert into tableA 
  (val1, val2) 
select top 1 'value', tableB.x from tableB where tableB.Y = @y
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have to use directly the insert into TABLE select... syntax. 
No "values" in this case.
People above have been faster than me but I agree with their proposals

Answer (score 1):

You're close:

```
INSERT INTO TableA(val1, val2)
SELECT top 1 "value",  X FROM TableB WHERE Y = @y
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
insert into TableA (val1,val2) 
   select top 1 "value",X from tableB where Y=@Y
```

Answer (score 1):

Another, inferior option that's less code change:
Define an interim value.

```
declare @scalarval int
select @scalarval = tableB.X from tableB where tableB.Y=@Y
insert into TableA (val1,val2) 
values("value",@scalarval)
```

However the insert into syntax is clearer.

Comment: I believe you are correct; I do not believe you can do top 1 select into a variable like that. Maybe select top 1?

Fixed query.

Answer (score 0):

```
StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
sb.Append("declare @id int select @id = top 1 TableB.id from TableB where TableB.DefaultName=@DefaultName order by TableB.id desc insert into TableA(col1,col2,col3,col4)  Values (@val1,@val2,@val3,@id)");
```

incorrect syntax near top .

How to done with this ??

//mssql server